Can you have two tables in a DB Preview to your SWA?
staticwebapp.database.config.json
Terminal Output after swa start
I tried to add this call the table after doing swa start. I used the proper url to the local host to /data-api/rest/Courses but it gives that error. I know that its reading because I changed the primary key and it was failing earlier because of that.
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/latest/download/dab.draft.schema.json",
  "data-source": {
    "database-type": "mssql",
    "connection-string": "@env('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING')"
  },
  "runtime": {
    "rest": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/rest"
    },
    "graphql": {
      "allow-introspection": true,
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/graphql"
    },
    "host": {
      "mode": "production",
      "cors": {
        "origins": [
          "http://localhost:5173"
        ],
        "allow-credentials": true
      },
      "authentication": {
        "provider": "StaticWebApps"
      }
    }
  },
  "entities": {
    "Schedule": {
      "source": "dbo.schedule",
      "rest": {
        "methods": ["get", "post", "put", "delete"],
        "path": "/Schedule"
      },
      "permissions": [
        {
          "role": "anonymous",
          "actions": ["read"]
        }
      ]
    },
     "Courses": {
        "source": "dbo.courses",
        "rest": {
           "methods": ["get", "post", "put", "delete"],
           "path": "/Courses"
         },
        "permissions": [
         {
           "role": "anonymous",
           "actions": ["read"]
         }
        ]
     }
  }
}



Please share the code for the database and JSON file in text format.

Hi Sampath. Not sure that you mean by the code for the database? I have included the database.config.json above. Please let me know what you are referring to specifically.

I see you used /data-api/rest/Courses and path  in staticwebapp.config.json. where did you configured the   routing  end ?

I used database preview as the way to connect my database to the front end. Apparently this handles the backend calls for me. All that I configured was the staticwebapp.config.json file. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-database-connections-support-in-azure-static-web-apps/
